# My Injected sessionFactory instance is null

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

When I inject my sessionFactory Bean using Java based configuration for Hibernate my bean is null and I don't know why. I've scoured the internet for answers but couldn't find any. I've looked over my configuration and compared it against guides online. Any answers are greatly appreciated.

Here's the exact error

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.SessionFactory.getCurrentSession()" because "com.example.demo.DemoApplication.sessionFactory" is null**

Here's my code

**HibernateConfiguration File, Annotation based.**

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class HibernateConfig {

@Bean
@Scope  //By default the scope is singleton which means that the IOC will only create a single instance of the bean and return that one reference for subsequent calls for that bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan( packagesToScan());  //Model packages to scan
    sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());

    return sessionFactory;
}

//Direct Physical Connection Information
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo");
    dataSource.setUsername("root");
    dataSource.setPassword("password");

    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager hibernateTransactionManager() {
    HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
    return transactionManager;
}
//List of Entities to scan
@Bean
public String [] packagesToScan() {
    return new String [] { "com.example.demo.Entities.Student" };
}
//Configures properties of our hibernate configuration, dialect, 

private final Properties hibernateProperties() {
    Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("show_sql", "true");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("current_session_context_class", "thread");

    return hibernateProperties;
}
}
```

My Main application where I'm attempting to inject my Session Factory singleton bean for use.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {
    
@Autowired
static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AnimalConfig.class,         HibernateConfig.class); // Makes the sessionFactory bean known to the IOC
    Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    
    (( ConfigurableApplicationContext )ctx).close();  //Close the applicationContext
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The container gets started when SpringApplication.run invokes. I think before all of this an injection and the usage of that bean does not makes sense. First you need to fire Springapplication and then the rest of the business logic.

Your bean isn't scanned and initialize at the moment of the injection.

Possible solution :

```
@Component
public class IOCAfterInitializationListener implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

@Autowired
static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
      Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
       //do whatever you want
    }
}
```

Comment: I see, What about using .getBean() to get the sessionFactory instead? I just wanna experiment with HQL queries in my main function

Comment: You shouldn't add anything to main() ot the  class of SpringBootApplication, Just let Spring do it's job. With the example above you can get the same functionality what you'd like. That method will be in IOCAfterInitializationListener invoked directly after spring finish it's job and the IOC container is ready to use